# How to pass Hex input parameters into dbt macro?

Tags: dbt

Context:

[Hex](https://hex.tech/blog/dbt-semantic-layer-integration/) now supports dbt's semantic layer. For example, you can use macros in the SQL cells. I have got the integration setup and verified my dbt macros work as expected when manually inputing parameters of the macro.

Problem:

How do I pass Hex input parameters into the macros? In dbt, the variables are in reference, so you don't need to bracket the inputs since the macro is bracketed. I believe the issue is that I need to quote the argument, otherwise dbt can't find the variable. There is no clear way to do this with hex. Anyone figure this out?

As an example:

my input parameters: `exp_name`.

I have a dbt macro: `do_something(x)`.

When calling this in dbt like `{{do_something('my_argument')}}` the macro works. However, when I call it in hex with the input parameter like `{{do_something(exp_name)}}`, dbt compiles it as missing variables and I no result is returned.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried manually quoting the variables with f-strings and setting these within the Jinja context but that did not work either.

Comment: You should probably contact Hex support about this.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Hex's documentation](https://learn.hex.tech/docs/connect-to-data/data-connections/dbt-integration#running-sql-against-the-dbt-server) it sounds like this isn't possible:
"Hex does not currently support mixing variables from the Hex and dbt Jinja contexts within the same section of Jinja. This means you cannot use a variable defined in a Hex project as an argument to a dbt macro."